# Accordion on page needs to have one of the boxes stay open and not be collapsable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, accordion

I have 3 tabs at the top of the page, and then an accordion in each one.

I need my bottom option in the accordion to always stay open at a fixed height of 200 pixels. 
I'm thinking I can take it out of the accordion and just set a default height, however I need it to switch within the tabbed system as well. Any ideas?

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>test page</title>

    <!-- Website Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skins/dark.css" type="text/css" media="screen">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>





    <!-- Scripts Styles -->


     <!-- Custom StyleSwitcher stylesheet -->
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
    </style>

    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/ie7.css"/>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper"><div class="one_half">

<div class="one_half last">
   <!-- Accordion -->



<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="sizes">Size ></li>    
        <li >A</a></li>
        <li >B</a></li>
        <li >C</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
<div id="accordion1">
    <h3 class="tab_first">A</h3>
    <div>Content </div>
    <h3>B</h3>
    <div>Content </div>

</div>
    <h3>C</h3>
    <div>Content that needs to stay open to 200 pixels </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="tabs-2"><div id="accordion2">
    <h3>First</h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <h3>Second</h3>
    <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
    <h3>Third</h3>
    <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div></div>
    <div id="tabs-3">Content that always needs to stay open to 200 pixels</div>
</div>


</div></div>



        <!-- FOOTER END -->   
        <!-- jQuery Scripts -->

    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <script>$(function() {
        $( "#accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3" ).accordion({active: 1 });
        autoheight: false 
        collapsible: false
        heightStyle: "fill"
        minHeight: 550,


        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact-form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>  


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle.

Comment: So you are trying to make the last option in each `<div id="accordion*">` always open at 200px?

Comment: So you are trying to make the last option in each <div id="#accordion*"> always open at 200px?

Yes I am

Comment: Did you check out my answer? Does it address your question?

Comment: It almost worked. See my comment below! I'm not sure what is missing because in a fiddle it works correctly. But the browser doesn't seem to be rendering it the same way at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/jYgnL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you're sticking with jQuery UI, you could make it it's own non-collapsible accordion, [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/quhbM/1/) to take a look (**Note** edited from my original answer to address your 200px height issue):

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="height_control">
                <div class="sub_accordion">
                    <h3>Heading1</h3>
                    <p>The content of heading1</p>
                    <h3>Heading2</h3>
                    <p>The content of heading2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="height_control">
                <div class="sub_accordion">
                    <h3>Always open Heading</h3>
                    <p>This content must always be open</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="height_control">
                <div class="sub_accordion">
                    <h3>Heading1</h3>
                    <p>The content of heading1</p>
                    <h3>Heading2</h3>
                    <p>The content of heading2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="height_control">
                <div class="sub_accordion">
                    <h3>Always open Heading</h3>
                    <p>This content must always be open</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
         <div class="accordion">
            <div class="height_control">
                <div class="sub_accordion">
                    <h3>Heading1</h3>
                    <p>The content of heading1</p>
                    <h3>Heading2</h3>
                    <p>The content of heading2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="height_control">
                <div class="sub_accordion">
                    <h3>Always open Heading</h3>
                    <p>This content must always be open</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#tabs").tabs({
         heightStyle: "content"
     });
      $( ".height_control:not(:last-child) .sub_accordion").accordion({
         collapsible: true,
          heightStyle: "content"
      });
     $( ".height_control:last-child .sub_accordion" ).accordion({
         collapsible: false,
         heightStyle: "fill"
     });
 });
```

And finally the CSS:

```
.height_control:last-child {
    height: 200px;    
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, other then now it only loads my active tab instead of the 2nd and 3rd tab's content as well (as it the 2nd and 3rd tabs on top don't accordion open)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you upload a screenshot as an update to your question or in [Photobucket](http://www.photobucket.com), or if you can't, then describe it in terms of the HTML tags in your code (e.g. "The content in `<div id='tab-3'>` is always collapsed").

Comment: Here it is 
http://d.pr/i/YwQn

Basically the first tab works just fine, content slides up and down and opens, but when going to the second tab, the bottom stays open, but boxes A and B won't open to display the content at all.

Comment: Take a look at [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quhbM/1/), and let me know if that works in your browser, it worked on mine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! It worked, I was missing a closing div tag as well, which may have been affecting it.